# Labels not showing in python igraph

Tags: python-3.x, igraph, spyder

Why vertex and edge labels won't appear in my graphs?

```
g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(3)
g.add_edges([(0,1), (1,2), (2,0)])
g.vs["label"]=["A", "B", "C"]
g.es["label"]=["ciao", "lol", "weee"]
layout = g.layout("kk")
plot(g, layout=layout, bbox=(300,300), margin=20)
```

[image]

All of this on macOS Catalina Version 10.15.2, in Spyder, python version 3.7.4

**SOLUTION**

As pointed out by Sreeram Nair, it is sufficient to save the plot in a pdf to get the graph with the labels.

```
plot(g, "my_graph.pdf")
```

gives the following

[image]

Comment: does `plot(g, vertex_label=["A", "B", "C"])` work?

Comment: @BSQL Nope, same result

Comment: you're using the igraph library yes?

Comment: @BSQL yeah sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, there's something wrong in the SVG implementation of Qt (on which the Python notebook is based), or igraph is using SVG incorrectly (not sure which is the case) and `QtSVG` is not able to render the fonts. Saving a figure to PDF or PNG or whatever format skips `Qt` entirely, so there's no problem there as explained in the [Github issue](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph/issues/185).

So, could you try saving it and try if the labels appear?